# Why WebClient not displaying web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight

The code below compiles but it does not display the text or photos of the website. I just want to run a program that involves HTTP communication with Silverlight. Any idea why I am not getting the website to display? I just get "error occurred" in the textBlock to display instead

```
namespace SilverlightApplication4
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        string baseUri = "http://yahoo.com";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();            

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);        
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(baseUri));
        }

        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
                textBox.Text = "Using WebClient: "+  e.Result;
            else
            {
                textBox.Text = e.Error.Message;
                textBlock.Text = "error occurred";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message. e.Error.Message is a good start to see whats wrong.

Comment: Is *anything* displayed? `WebClient` is going to download the HTML, and your code is going to display that. It certainly won't render the HTML or show any images in the text box.

Comment: I get the message "System.Security.SecurityException ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Security error. at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_DisplayClassa.<EndGetResponse>b_9(Object sendState) at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c_DisplayClass4.<BeginOnUI>b_1(Object sendState) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback beginMethod, Object state) at ..

Comment: ...System.Net.Browser.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request, IAsyncResult result) at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBitsResponseCallback(IAsyncResult result)"

Answer (score 1):

It is a crossdomain issue where the xml is not present in the server as a result you are getting the exception

Heres a link where I found the issue you can go through it

[Security Exception](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/375584/Using-WebClient-to-download-string-from-ASP-NET-We)

Comment: Even if I add the clientaccesspolicy.xml to the folder that contains this project, I get the same error.

My clientaccesspolicy.xml file contains this

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="*">      
        <domain uri="http://www.yahoo.com/"/>
        </allow-from>      
      <grant-to>
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>

I just want to be able to display the content from yahoo.com in my silverlight project